# Regression analysis with small data set

Tags: regression, discrete-time

We've performed a regression analysis with 14 data points (Y's) that originate from 9 X's (plant batches were split up).
I'm well aware that this is a small data set and there are caveats. However, the regression we have gives a R-sqrd (pred) of 85%,  residuals are all good, there are no anomalous points or residuals outside two SD; lack of fit is 0.43.

Some of the data is subjective - growers assigned a rating of pest infestation on the plants from 1 (bad) to (5) barely any. We've counted the number of weeks of pest attack of score 1,2 or 3 to balance out this subjectivity (only scores of 3 or more are flagged); this makes one X.

Given this background and R-sqrd, can we say we have good correlation and provide justification to put the multiple X's we've identified under more scrutiny?

Comment: You have nine observations of your independent variable and 14 observations of your dependent variable? In any event, I suggest reading my post here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/64148/73930. I have another post where I show how to do the F-test for a regression: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/439341/247274. As I mentioned in the first, though, such a high $R^2$ almost doesn’t require math to say that it’s higher than 0.

Answer (score 2):

**Overfit Model**

Because you have such few observations in your model relative to the number of predictor variables, your model is likely an **overfit model**. An overfit model is too complex for the data - it has too many predictor variables for the number of observations.

**Problems with R Squared in an Overfit Model**

**A symptom of an overfit model is a high R squared value**, as explained by Jim Frost in his article on *"Five Reasons Why Your R-squared can be Too High"*
(https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/r-squared-too-high/):

*"While the R2 looks good, there can be serious problems with an overfit model. For one thing, the regression coefficients represent the noise rather than the genuine relationships in the population. Additionally, an overfit regression model is tailor-made to fit the random quirks of one sample and is unlikely to fit the random quirks of another sample. Thus, overfitting a regression model reduces its generalizability outside the original dataset."*

**Investigate If Model Overfits the Data**

So before you make any decisions based on your current model, **you need to investigate further whether your current model is an overfit model**, since an overfit model can produce misleading R squared values, as well as misleading regression coefficients and p-values.  If you'll base your decisions on misleading values, everything you do further down the road will be questionable.

Jim Frost has another nice article on *Overfitting Regression Models: Problems, Detection, and Avoidance* you can refer to (https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/overfitting-regression-models/). In this article, he explains that you can use a different kind of R squared to detect overfitting: **the predicted R squared**.

**Predicted R Squared Versus Regular R Squared**

If you are able to compute the predicted R squared for your model, you can then **compare the predicted R-squared to the regular R-squared and see if there is a large discrepancy between their values** (e.g., predicted R squared could be equal to almost 0% while regular R squared could be equal to 85%). To quote Jim Frost:

*"If there is a large discrepancy between the two values, your model doesn’t predict new observations as well as it fits the original dataset. The results are not generalizable, and there’s a good chance you’re overfitting the model."*

In a separate article, titled *How to Interpret Adjusted R-Squared and Predicted R-Squared in Regression Analysis*
(https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/interpret-adjusted-r-squared-predicted-r-squared-regression/), Jim Frost states:

*"Predicted R-squared helps you determine whether you are overfitting a regression model. Again, an overfit model includes an excessive number of terms, and it begins to fit the random noise in your sample.*

*By its very definition, it is not possible to predict random noise. Consequently, if your model fits a lot of random noise, the predicted R-squared value must fall. A predicted R-squared that is distinctly smaller than R-squared is a warning sign that you are overfitting the model. Try reducing the number of terms."*

Comment: That was my concern @Isabella Ghement,  but that's why I mentioned that predicted R-sqrd was 85%

Comment: Oh, I missed that bracket clarification about the predicted R squared. What was the regular R squared?

Comment: 93% adjusted,  95% regular